# Cognito's Google integration callback url as localhost is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am configuring googles authentication with cognito but can't get to work the localhost domain with the integration. Everytime I put localhost on *Allowed callback URLs*, I get a 403 error page even though the input says that localhost is valid:

[image: localhost cognito]

The localhost is also configured on Google's side:
[image: localhost on GCP]

But if I access the Hosted UI this error is shown (with a custom integration I also get an error):
[image: hosted UI]

Also try `https` instead of `http` but with the same result.

I know is something with localhost because when its removed from the list, everything works.

Is this normal?, or maybe am blind and missing something obvious?

Comment: Google Developer Console Configuration: Ensure that you have also added http://localhost:<PORT> (and https:// variant if necessary) to the authorized redirect URIs in the Google Developer Console where you've set up your OAuth 2.0 credentials. Both Cognito and Google should agree on the allowed redirect URIs.

Comment: I configure localhost on the Google side (`http://localhost:3000`) but sadly the result is the same

Comment: When do you see this 403, when you've authenticated with google or when you hit the hosted ui for the first time?  Double check you've set everything according to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html#cognito-user-pools-social-idp-step-1) it's easy to miss a setting.

Comment: The 403 appears when I try to access to the hosted ui (even on an incognito window). And in a custom integration amplify just throws an error. If I remove localhost keeping just my domain with https, everything works